# Problem deserializing JSON into KeyValuePair using JSON.NET

Tags: json.net, deserialization

This is part of a larger problem I am working on. However, I have attempted to break it down to the simplest form possible.

I am using JSON.Net, and trying to deserialize several JSON objects into KeyValuePair, but I cannot get even a simple example test to work.

```
var pair = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(@"""the key"": ""the value""");
```

This throws a JsonReaderException -- **After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: :. Line 1, position 10.**

It seems to choke on the colon character, which I find rather odd. I've used JSON.Net several times before, and never have run into anything like this.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, got this figured out. Has to be in the following form to deserialize properly:

```
{"Key":"the key","Value":"the value"}
```